# Laravel 5.5 install on Ubuntu 16.04 error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, installation, composer-php

When I am trying to intall Laravel to Ubuntu with the following command:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

I get the following error (see following image) 
[image: Ubuntu Laravel Installation error]

When I run:

```
php --ini
```

I get the following output (see following image)
[image]

I really cannot see what the problem is, all help i appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you don't have `ext-zip` installed.

Comment: This ^^ Ask an Ubuntu geek what to do ... which is, more or less, get all the prerequisite software installed first.  I would guess it to be something like "sudo apt install ext-zip".

Answer (score 9):

I will give you one small tip, whenever any error occurs, kindly try reading through it.

As it says **requires ext-zip** that means it is require extension ZIP installed to perform required operation.

So all you need to do as of now is to install ZIP extension for php using this command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```